# xpath with xsl:when test

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need of display BIG on planets with diameter higher than average diameter or SMALL without using avg function (XSLT 1.0)

I have tried to use xsl:when with a condition like diameter > sum(....) div count(nom), but it doesn't work :

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/systeme_solaire">
    <html lang="fr">
        <head>
            <title>Les planètes</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="planete[nom!='Terre']">
                <xsl:sort select ="diametre" order="descending" data-type="number" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="planete" >
    <ul>
        <p><b><xsl:value-of select="nom"/> : </b></p>
        <li>Distance au soleil: <xsl:value-of select="distance"/><xsl:value-of select="distance/@unit"/></li>
        <li>Masse: <xsl:value-of select="masse"/> <xsl:value-of select="masse/@unit"/></li>
        <li>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="diametre > ((sum(diametre[unit='diamètre terrestre']*sum(diametre[unit='km']))+sum(diametre[unit='km'])) div count(nom))">
   BIG
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   SMALL
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>  Diamètre: <xsl:value-of select="diametre"/> <xsl:value-of select="diametre/@unit"/></li>
        <xsl:if test="satellite>0"><li>Nombre de satellites: <xsl:value-of select="satellite"/></li></xsl:if>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML file used (diameter of planets differents from earth are defined according to earth diameter ratio) :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
 
<systeme_solaire>
 
<planete type="tellurique">
    <nom>Vénus</nom>
    <distance unit="UA" >0.7</distance>
    <masse unit="masse terrestre">0.8</masse>
    <diametre unit="diamètre terrestre">0.9</diametre>
</planete>
 
<planete type="tellurique">
    <nom>Terre</nom>
    <distance unit="km" >149600000</distance>
    <masse unit="kg">5.98e24</masse>
    <diametre unit="km">12756</diametre>
    <satellite>1</satellite>
</planete>
 
<planete type="tellurique">
    <nom>Mars</nom>
    <distance unit="UA" >1.5</distance>
    <masse unit="masse terrestre">0.1</masse>
    <diametre unit="diamètre terrestre">0.5</diametre>
    <satellite>2</satellite>
</planete>
 
</systeme_solaire>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems :

1. First you need to calculate you average diameter outside the
   template `planete` in order to reach all planets then pass this
   average to you template
2. Then you xpath is incorrect : wrong parenthesis, `unit` is an attribute so you need to use `@`. You need something like this :
   `((sum(//diametre[@unit='diamètre
   terrestre'])*//diametre[@unit='km'])+//diametre[@unit='km']) div
   count(//nom)`
   **Edit** : You also need to calculate the actual diameter of your current planet base on earth diameter, you can do this by adding another parameter `<xsl:with-param name="terre" select="//diametre[@unit='km']"/>` and using it `<xsl:when test="diametre*$terre > $avg">`

I've updated you XSLT like so :

**Solution 1**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/systeme_solaire">
    <html lang="fr">
        <head>
            <title>Les planètes</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="planete[nom!='Terre']">
                <xsl:sort select ="diametre" order="descending" data-type="number" />
                <xsl:with-param name="avg" select="((sum(//diametre[@unit='diamètre terrestre'])*//diametre[@unit='km'])+//diametre[@unit='km']) div count(//nom)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="terre" select="//diametre[@unit='km']"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="planete" >
   <xsl:param name="avg"/>
   <xsl:param name="terre"/>
    <ul>
        <p><b><xsl:value-of select="nom"/> : </b></p>
        <li>Distance au soleil: <xsl:value-of select="distance"/><xsl:value-of select="distance/@unit"/></li>
        <li>Masse: <xsl:value-of select="masse"/> <xsl:value-of select="masse/@unit"/></li>
        <li>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="diametre*$terre > $avg">
   BIG
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   SMALL
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>  Diamètre: <xsl:value-of select="diametre"/> <xsl:value-of select="diametre/@unit"/></li>
        <xsl:if test="satellite>0"><li>Nombre de satellites: <xsl:value-of select="satellite"/></li></xsl:if>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit** to add michael suggestion (calculate the average diameter as the ratio) :
**Solution 2**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="planete[nom!='Terre']">
    <xsl:sort select ="diametre" order="descending" data-type="number" />
    <xsl:with-param name="avg" select="(sum(//diametre[@unit='diamètre terrestre'])+1) div count(//nom)"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
...
<xsl:template match="planete" >
   <xsl:param name="avg"/>
   ...
     <xsl:when test="diametre > $avg">
   ...
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to take into account that the diameter you test needs to be multiplied by the earth diameter.

Comment: Thanks, for another xml file, I have created a variable with first letter uppercase and I'm trying to use xsl:apply-templates to display it but it doesn't work : <xsl:variable name="$nomUpper" select="concat(translate(substring(nom/text(),1,1), $smallcase, $uppercase),
          substring(nom/text(), 2),
          substring(' ', 1 div not(position()=last()))
         )" />  <xsl:apply-templates select="$nomUpper" />

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here but `select` in `apply-template` is be used to process nodes selected by an expression not variable. If you want to pass a variable to a template use `xsl:with-param` in `apply-template` and `xsl:param` in the template like in the above answer. Also if this answers what you asked for please accepted it and create another question for any new problem.

Comment: Since Earth is excluded, I don't see why you need to use the actual units. Simply calculate the average diameter as the ratio.

Comment: @michael.hor257k You're right, I just used the same calculation as mauris did but this way we don't need to recalculate the diameter or another param.

Comment: When I try to run solution 1, it seems to doens't work : nothing displayed

Comment: Oops ,my bad I forgot a line on my edit `<xsl:param name="terre"/>`